# Adding the name of a group on the y axis in bold to a horizontal error bar plot, changing spaces in between labels ánd add an extra text column

Tags: r, image, ggplot2, dplyr, errorbar

Ive got data on 2 regression models (both got an estimate with corresponding lower and upper ends of a CI). Both models include 3 variables (age, sex, and smoking status). The variable `term` (corresponding to the variables in the model) is ordered so it appears in the order I've specified.

The data looks as follows:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)

mydata <- structure(list(term = structure(c(1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 
5L, 5L), .Label = c("Age (years)", "Sex (male)", "Never smoking (reference)", 
"Current smoking", "Former smoking", ">90 (reference)", "60-89", 
"<60"), class = c("ordered", "factor")), estimate = c(1.5, 2.2, 
0.7, 1.8, 1, 1.5, 2.2, 0.7, 1.6), conf_low = c(1.3, 1.8, 0.9, 
1, 1, 1.3, 1.8, 0.9, 1), conf_high = c(1.7, 2.6, 0.5, 2.6, 1, 
1.7, 2.6, 0.5, 2.4), model = structure(c(1L, 2L, 1L, 2L, NA, 
1L, 2L, 1L, 2L), .Label = c("Model 1", "Model 2"), class = c("ordered", 
"factor")), label = structure(c(3L, 6L, 1L, 5L, 2L, 3L, 6L, 1L, 
4L), .Label = c("0.7 (0.9-0.5)", "1.0 (1.0-1.0)", "1.5 (1.3-1.7)", 
"1.6 (1.0-2.4)", "1.8 (1.0-2.6)", "2.2 (1.8-2.6)"), class = "factor")), row.names = c(NA, 
-9L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))

head(mydata)
# A tibble: 6 x 6
  term                      estimate conf_low conf_high model   label        
  <ord>                        <dbl>    <dbl>     <dbl> <ord>   <fct>        
1 Age (years)                    1.5      1.3       1.7 Model 1 1.5 (1.3-1.7)
2 Age (years)                    2.2      1.8       2.6 Model 2 2.2 (1.8-2.6)
3 Sex (male)                     0.7      0.9       0.5 Model 1 0.7 (0.9-0.5)
4 Sex (male)                     1.8      1         2.6 Model 2 1.8 (1.0-2.6)
5 Never smoking (reference)      1        1         1   NA      1.0 (1.0-1.0)
6 Current smoking                1.5      1.3       1.7 Model 1 1.5 (1.3-1.7)
```

And I've made the following plot:

```
ggplot(data=mydata, 
       aes(x=estimate, 
           y=fct_rev(term), 
           color=model)) + 
  geom_point(position=position_dodge(width=0.3)) + 
  geom_errorbarh(aes(xmin=conf_low, xmax=conf_high, height=0.15), position=position_dodge(width=0.3))
```

[image]

Now im further trying to achieve twothings that I can't get working:

1. I'd like to add a title/variable name above `Never smoking (reference)` in the plot on the Y axis, so that just above that label it says **Smoking status** (in bold). I could add another row to the original dataframe, but then the distance between the title and 'never smoking' will be kind of large. Is there a way to add a title otherwise, ór a way to adjust the specific distance between certain lables on the Y axis?
2. There is also a column `label` in the dataset, corresponding to the estimate and 95%CI. I'd like to add this as an extra column on the right of the plot, so that they are on the same height as their corresponding points/error-bars.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One option to achieve your desired result would be to use `annotation_custom` to add the group header and to use `geom_text` to add the text labels for the error bars:

Note: To put the annotation outside of the plot I use `coord_cartesian(clip = "off")`

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(forcats)

ggplot(
  data = mydata,
  aes(
    x = estimate,
    y = fct_rev(term),
    color = model
  )
) +
  geom_point(position = position_dodge(width = 0.3)) +
  geom_errorbarh(aes(xmin = conf_low, xmax = conf_high, height = 0.15), position = position_dodge(width = 0.3)) +
  annotation_custom(grob = grid::textGrob(label = "Smoking status", gp = grid::gpar(fontface = "bold"), hjust = 1), xmin = -Inf, xmax = -Inf, ymin = 3.2, ymax = 3.2) +
  geom_text(aes(x = max(conf_high) * 1.05, label = label, group = model), position = position_dodge(width = 0.3), hjust = 0, show.legend = FALSE, color = "black") +
  scale_x_continuous(expand = expansion(mult = c(.05, .3))) +
  coord_cartesian(clip = "off")
#> Warning: Removed 1 rows containing missing values (geom_point).
```

[image]

Comment: Hi @stefan, thanks very much for your answer, it resolves my problem. As a follow-up question, would you know how to remove the NA factor level that is associated with the model variable (in the legend I mean)? Thanks.

Comment: Quick option: Set the breaks: `+ scale_color_viridis_d(breaks = c("Model 1", "Model 2"))`

Comment: If possible I've got another follow-up question. When the text gro becomes more text than the y axis is broad (for example put "The smoking status of the patients") then it is not visible partly anymore. Is there any way to adjust this? I figured I could change the position of the textGrob with hjust, but then it overlaps with the plot.

Comment: You could increase the plot margin or the left margin of the axis text using `theme(axis.text.y = element_text(margin = margin(r = 2.2, l = 88, "pt")))` (2.2 on the right is the default for theme_grey)

Comment: Just one more question then> I've put a title above the Y axis using another `annotation_custom`, but now I need to adjust the vertical limits of the Y axis. I though I could do this by manipulating the `t` and `b` in `theme(axis.text.y=element_text(margin=margin(t=1, r=2.2, b=10, l=40, "pt")))`, but that does not seem to do anything to the plot...

Comment: Hm. Always a bit tricky to adress the right theme element. `axis.text` is just for the tick labels. If I got you right you need some space on top of the plot. I would try with `theme(plot.margin = margin(t = 50, 5.5, 5.5, 5.5, "pt"))`